# Check if the following are perpendicular.

Tags: calculus, geometry, vectors

I have these expressions :

$$2x+2y-5=0 \\ x=3-t,y=2+t,z=1-3t$$

I need to check if they are perpendicular.

This is what I did :

The following vectors represent the expressions

$\langle 2,2,0\rangle ,\langle -1,1,-3\rangle $

Then :

$$\langle 2,2,0\rangle *\langle -1,1,-3\rangle =(2*-1)+(2*1)+0=0$$

Therefore I got that they are perpendicular, but for some reason my book says they are not perpendicular.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: note that  :$$2x+2y−5=0\\x=3−t,y=2+t,z=1−3t$$ so $$t=-x+3 \\t=y-2\\t=\frac{-z+1}{3} $$ then line equation is :$$\frac{x-3}{-1}=\frac{y-2}{1}=\frac{z-1}{-3} $$ vector of line is :$<-1,1,-3>$

Comment: @MichaelBurr They intersect incase the scalar multiplication equals to 0, as I shown above, then why they dont perpendicular?

Comment: $$<-1,1,-3> * <2,2,0>=0 \space$$ it means two vector are perpendicular , and It means line and plane are parallel

Comment: @user242774 I think that you're confusing the various definitions.  You've shown that the normal vector to the first plane is perpendicular to the direction of the line.  This means, abusing notation, that the plane and the line are more like parallel than perpendicular.

Comment: @MichaelBurr typo edited.

Comment: Please use \langle and \rangle instead of < and >, because it formats better.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I showed that the direction is perpendicular, that means that the two vectors cut at 90 degrees, how can they be parallel when they cut at 90 degrees?

Comment: @user242774 The first object is a *plane* not a line.  The vector $\langle 2,2,0\rangle$ is the normal vector to the plane.  The second object is a line and you've computed the vector in the direction of the line.  Place a piece of paper on your desk, then take a pencil and put it straight up out of your paper (that's the normal vector $\langle 2,2,0\rangle$).  Then place another pencil perpendicular to the first pencil above the paper (so that it forms a $T$).  This represents your line.  The normal vector and the line are perpendicular, but the plane (the paper) and the line are parallel.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Great explanation thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're given a plane and a straight line, resp.:

$$\begin{align}&\pi:\;\;2x+2y-5=0\\{}\\
&\ell:\;\;(3,2,1)+t(-1,1,-3)\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R\end{align}$$

This line and this plane are perpendicular to each other iff a normal vector to the plane is parallel to a (the) direction vector of the line.

A (the) normal to the plane is $\;(2,2,0)\;$ , and a (the) direction vector of the line is $\;(-1,1,-3)\;$ , so the question is: are these two last vectors parallel? Or what is the same: is one of the vectors a scalar multiple of the second one?

Comment: I understood what you explained, but I cannot understand why I need to show that one can be represented as a scalar multiple of the second one for perpendicular, I show that one can be represented as a scalar of the second one if I want to show they are parallel not perpendicular.

Comment: Observe that two vectors in space are **parallel** iff one is a scalar multiple of the other one. On *your* case, we want to check whether the direction vector of the line is parallel to the **normal** vector of the plane...and it isn't $\;\rightarrow\;$ the line is **not** perpendicular to the plane. In this case, it happens to be the normal and the direction vector of the line are perpendicular, and thus the line is **parallel** to the plane.